# Rails - Closed terminal and rebooted machine - now bash tells me rails isn't installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsapps, learn-ruby-on-rails

Running OSX Mavericks, ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0], rvm 1.25.23 (master), and rails-4.1.0 (allegedly)

I'm working through the [railsapps.org](http://railsapps.github.io/) book on [learning rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) and made it about 1/2 way through yesterday.  When I stopped for the day, I closed out iTerm2 and shut off the Macbook Pro.  Today, I powered up, opened iTerm, navigated to my working directory (~/rubyonrails/learn-ruby) and entered `rails -v`.

I see this:

```
`Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.`
```

So I run `sudo gem install rails` and it shows that it has installed rails-4.1.0.  Now `rails -v` still gives me the same error message above.

I tried also running `rvm use ruby-2.1.1@learn-rails` first and I still get the error message.

So I'm a little stuck and I can't figure out what to do to get rails working.  Also, how do I go about setting up the bash environment such that I don't have to go through this each time?  It would be nice to nav to my working directory and just start work without having to do a bunch of re-installation and reconfiguration each time.

Regards,
Jeff

Comment: What output do you get when you run `type gem` at a shell prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please type in your shell:

```
$ bash --login
```

and then repeat your commands.

```
rails -v
```

Also try to call it with the full path: 
like:

```
/your/path/to/rails -v
```

I think that the shell just doesn't know where rvm/rails etc is located.

You can solve this by entering:

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Comment: Ok, so running the source command fixed it.  Is this something I have to do every time I open a shell?  If so, I can just add this to my .bashrc and/or .bash_profile?

Comment: Installing RVM should have modified your shell init to do this. I suggest asking on the RVM IRC channel for help http://rvm.io/support/irc as the maintainers are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch to the `ruby-2.1.1@learn-rails` ruby/gemset combo, and do `gem list`, what do you see?

The way people usually use rvm is to have every project folder specify the ruby & gemset it uses (they don't all have to be different).  This is done with files called `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`.  These should contain, in your case, `ruby-2.1.1` and `learn-rails` respectively.

Set these if you haven't already, then leave the folder and enter it again.  Then do `bundle install` to install the gems for the project into the rvm/gemset combo.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you ran

```
sudo gem install rails
```

The error message telling you to do this comes from your system Ruby, which doesn't know that you want to use RVM.

RVM installs gems into your user-space directory. By using sudo, you're bypassing this and installing it into (effectively) the superuser space, i.e. globally.

If you instead just run

```
gem install rails
```

then you'll be using RVM's copy of the `gem` utility rather than the globally installed version.